# SQL Error [1452] [23000]: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, dbeaver

I have created tables in SQL as shown below, but when I try to insert values, I get the following error and I'm not sure why:

> SQL Error [1452] [23000]: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`N01581969`.`Attending`, CONSTRAINT `Attending_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`patientID`) REFERENCES `Patient` (`patientID`))

Physician table

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor 
(
    employeeID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    first_name varchar (255),
    last_name varchar (255), 
    position varchar (255)
);
```

Patients

```
CREATE TABLE Patient 
(
    patientID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    first_name varchar (255),
    last_name varchar (255), 
    HCN INT, 
    PCP varchar(255)
);
```

Nurses

```
CREATE TABLE Nurse 
(
    nurseID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    first_name varchar (255),
    last_name varchar (255), 
    n_position varchar (255)
);
```

Medical History

```
CREATE TABLE MedicalHistory 
(
    historyID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    med_condition varchar (255),
    medication varchar (255)
);
```

Comment: Did you create the Doctor table? Can you do `SHOW CREATE TABLE Doctor` ? It might help to see your insert statement too.

Comment: We need to see your insert statement so we can work out which table has the constraint that's causing your error.  Take out any personal information though.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which table you are adding a value with, but it looks like you're adding one in the first table. If you are, one reason could be because `patient_id` is supposed to be auto increment so you don't have to add value to it. When you are inserting value to that table you will start at `first_name` instead of the `patient_id`.